# AWS ALB redirect url EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a subdomain app.service.com

i am hosting an app in EKS with two different paths(app1, app2) in my ingress controller. both paths currently have same app running

Is it possible to rewrite the url http://app.service.com/app1/regions and http://app.service.com/app2/regions to http://app.service.com/regions

in short the path tag app1/app2 should be removed for any endpoint i will call. this was possible for me in azure kubernetes with rewrite rule when i used ngnix ingress
is there any alternative method for AWS kubernetes with ALB as ingress

Answer (score 1):

The AWS LB Controller supports annotations that allow you to configure this type of redirect: look for item `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.${action-name}`.

Below is the sample ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ingress
  annotations:
       alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.redirect-to-eks: '[{"type": "redirect", "redirectConfig": {"host":"www.example.com","path":"/eks/"}}]'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /path1
            backend:
              serviceName: rule-path1
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /path2
            backend:
              serviceName: rule-path2
              servicePort: use-annotation
```

You can find more information about it in this [document](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#traffic-routing).

above configuration will redirect  `www.example.com/path1/abc` to `www.example.com/eks/abc`. As if you visit `www.example.com/path1/abc`, you should be redirected to `www.example.com/eks/abc`

Comment: hello  i am new to this  sorry i didnt understand what path should i keep in the redirect-to-eks action

i am assuming that if i open {{URL}}/path1/abc it will redirect to {{URL}}/eks/abc
is it the case ?

Comment: yes the redirect is configured to redirect requests from `www.example.com/path1` to `www.example.com/eks` (keeping the rest of the path after /path1 intact). So if you `visit www.example.com/path1/abc`, you should be redirected to `www.example.com/eks/abc`.